# Impossible to restore my backup site with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wordfence

Hello I try to restore my site thanks to phpmyadmin but I have met many trouble.
I think the problem come from the path that doesn't correspond with mine (because it's a new computer) but I tried to correct it impossible to see my website back. It sounds like also there is a sort of protection put it with en extension in wordpress called wordfence who cannot let me see my website.

thank you very much for your help.
this is the screen:
[image]

Comment: See this: https://www.wordfence.com/help/firewall/optimizing-the-firewall/#removing-the-optimization

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with the very little information provided but you may want to try disabling wordfence by renaming the folder /wp-content/plugins/wordfence to /wp-content/plugins/wordfence_off or some such. This will stop it looking for the file.

Comment: Hello,thank you for your answer but it doesn't work in my side. As you could see the error is this one: Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\amrla\Desktop\TFE2016\UwAmp\www\laghmich/wordfence-waf.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0 but in my folder it's not in the same path I want to change it but i don't know in which file i can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the paths may have changed you can try this :

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-with-wordfence-2/

In this case, you will need to delete references to wordfence-waf in the .htaccess, .user.ini, and/or php.ini files.

You can search these files for “wordfence-waf”. These references will look like so:

php_value auto_prepend_file "/path_to_file/wordfence-waf.php"

auto_prepend_file = '/home/username/website.com/wordfence-waf.php'

Comment: Hello Ryan, thank you very much I fixed my problem thanks to you. However I met a new one ok i  removed all the wordfence security but know i have this page instead of my website it told me to install it but normally it should show me my site no ?

Answer (score 0):

it tooks me to this page :
http://localhost/wp-admin/install.php

not the page of my website.
Am I suppose to modify something other ?
thank you very much for your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI2Mk.png)

Comment: It's likely that the website cannot establish the database connection. Check that the wp-config.php file in the root of the website has the correct connection info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback i will check and let you know i appreciate your help :)